# Order List - List Items numbers disappear when using dynamic class in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have the following css:

```
.hide-item {
  display: none;
}
.show-item {
  display: block;
}
```

And in my template I have the following code:

```
   <ol>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let issue of selectedIssues; let i = index;">
          <li [ngClass]="i >= issuesCount ? 'show-item' : 'hide-item'"><a href="{{issue.html_url}}" target="_blank">{{issue.title}}</a></li>
      </ng-container>
    </ol>
```

Prior to putting the ternary operator in there it would list the items with numbers. Now, it lists the items, and only the items that are >= i but the numbers no longer appear. There are no bullet points, just a blank space and then the items. How come?

Comment: can you provide stackblitz for better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

In html

```
<ol>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let issue of propTemplateResult; let i = index;">
        <li [class]="i >= issuesCount ? 'show-item' : 'hide-item'"><a href="{{issue.html_url}}" target="_blank">{{issue.title}}</a></li>
    </ng-container>
</ol>
```

In CSS

```
.hide-item {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.show-item {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: here issuesCount value should be less than result array length

Answer (score 0):

> The issue with `[ngClass]` value format. The format should be as -

```
{ 
  cssClassName1 : {Boolean},
  cssClassName2 : {Boolean}
  ...
}
```

> So whichever property gets the true value will be applied as class into the element.

** So your modified code should like -**

```
<ol>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let issue of propTemplateResult; let i = index;">
        <li [class]="{'show-item' : (i >= issuesCount), 'hide-item' : (i < issuesCount)}">
      <a href="{{issue.html_url}}" target="_blank">{{issue.title}}</a></li>
    </ng-container>
</ol>
```